# get specific row on database when joining 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

for example i have 2 of this table:

```
place                         facility
|placeID|address|price|       |facilityID|placeID|facilityname|
|   1   | add1  | pr1 |       |   1      |   1   | internet   |
|   2   | add2  | pr2 |       |   2      |   1   |   TV       |
                              |   3      |   2   | internet   |
```

my program was to choose the facility, and then return the rows of specific value, for example, i want to choose `internet` and `tv` and then it will return the `place with add1 not add2`. how to do this with query?

edit:
normally the output would be like this:

```
|placeID|address|price|facilityname|
|  1    | add1  | pr1 |  internet  |
|  1    | add1  | pr1 |     TV     |
```

my expected out put would be:

```
|placeID|address|price|
|   1   |  add1 | pr1 |
```

so i think i want to merge the row with same value, it is possible?

Comment: You can use INNER JOIN

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: INNER JOIN would return duplicate value, adding DISTINCT wont help either. for example if i use inner join and distinct and select facility name with internet and tv, it would return add1 twice.

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql-Server? Can't be both...

Comment: Use Distinct  and also exclude the column facilityname from select part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only addresses that have both internet and TV service, you simply can group by place and count the distinct services that the place has attached.

```
SELECT p.address
FROM place p
JOIN facility f
  ON p.placeID = f.placeID
WHERE f.facilityname IN ('TV', 'internet')
GROUP BY p.address
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT f.facilityname) = 2
```

Comment: it worked! but it is possible if i also want to get the price value?

Comment: never mind, as long as i can get the placeID value its all good. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT place.placeID, place.address, place.price
FROM facility 
INNER JOIN place ON facility.placeID = place.placeID
WHERE facilityname IN ('internet','TV')
```

Comment: this one would also return add2 value, where it only have internet as facility

Comment: What is the actual requirement , You always want only the PlaceID 1 AND Add1 ?